# Adding CSV file from Google Drive to ArcGIS online Map Viewer

Tags: arcgis-online, csv, arcgis-online-webmap, google-drive

I am trying to add a layer from web in ArcGIS Online's Map Viewer. I had uploaded a csv with proper location details (Long , Lat) in my Google Drive and made it public shareable link.

When I try to import it to ArcGIS Online it says

> The layer was not created because no locations could be found. Make
> sure your data has valid location information.

Is there a solution for this?

[image]

Comment: Your first coordinates are in the sea, https://www.google.ca/maps/place/20%C2%B038'09.1%22N+92%C2%B021'09.7%22E/@20.6358661,92.3351849,14z what are you expecting?

Comment: Its on the beach . If you turn the satellite view on you will see. But I dont think esri provides it only for location on flat earth but not in waters!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When adding a spreadsheet to AGOL, it tends to work better by doing it from the **Content** page.

[image: AGOL content page, add item]

1. Click **Add Item** and then **From a Cloud Drive**.
2. Follow the prompts to authorize AGOL to access your Google Drive.
3. On the next menu, you will be able to sort/filter your Drive for files that are compatible with AGOL. Note that you can even import Google Sheets themselves, without needed to export or save as a CSV, if that happens to apply to you. Find your file and continue. *Note that I am using a Google Sheet, but the process is the same.*

[image: add item from google drive prompt]

4. AGOL will do a quick analysis of the data, and will make its best guess at the fields and data types are.

   - If your data has coordinate fields, it will usually catch that and default to those for the output point locations.
   - If it doesn't pick your fields automatically, you do have the option of manually specifying which fields serve as the location.

[image: import table next step, specifying location]

5. Give your content item a name, tags, &c., and complete the process. Your spreadsheet should now be its own content item in your AGOL Organization.

Final note! As with other uploaded content items, you do have the ability to update the data down the road without making a new layer. Simply click **Update Data**, and you can reconnect to the original file in your Drive to update the layer.

[image: overwriting google sheets layer]

Comment: Thank you. But I dont have a AGOL organisational account rather a public account. In this account the option "From a Cloud Drive" is not Available.
Is there any other way?

Comment: Ah, I don't know if there is, though I don't use a Public Account myself. Can you use the "Add From File" option and load the CSV directly to the Map Viewer, rather than through your Drive?

Comment: Oh i see. I know the Add from file option but i wanted it from drive because i needed it to update on the go and to let some others to make edit to the data. However Thanks for your advise.       One more thing could you tell me the pricing of AGOL for individual using? Or is it free?

Comment: ESRI's pricing is notoriously opaque from one organization to the other. You'd have to contact them directly.
If you need a single online dataset that multiple users can edit, you could use [Google My Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/).

Comment: i cant thank you enough..

Answer (score 3):

To have the web map load the CSV data directly from Google Drive, you need to

1. Share it with "anyone"
2. Figure out the exact URL to the CSV export/download, which should be something like https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1kn3kP3gr24OI-4UrUDjNEwQXf-OOhZyG (but with a different id).
3. In the Map Viewer, "Add layer from Web".

See for example https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=438724faf68c4c0e874e14bd20b36196